# Give Slave Port Name an Alias or Rename

Tags: c, serial-port, pty

Is it possible to give a Slave Port Name an alias? What function would I use?

I have created a Pseudo Terminal and I want to give an alias to the slave port. So I want to rename `/dev/ttys000` to `/dev/gps0`.

Is it possible to do such as thing? And what function would I use?

Comment: Hang on a sec. What are you trying to do here? Pseudoterminals aren't interchangeable with serial ports… they're primarily around for use by terminal emulators.

Answer (score 1):

See [ln](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln) to create symbolic links?

```
sudo ln -s /dev/ttys000 /dev/gps0
```